# how to set 2 iterator on one hashmap

Tags: java, loops, iterator, hashmap

I know how to iterate over a hashmap but I'm not sure whether we can set 2 iterators on a single Hashmap or not?

let say I have the following hashmap:

```
Map m = new HashMap<Integer, String>;
m.put(112334,"A");
m.put(221345,"B");
m.put(321411,"C");
m.put(431254,"D");
```

I want to get all combinations of values out of the Hashmap in such a way that no pair is repeated. So in this case, 4 values --> 6 pairs (AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD). I'm thinking of something like:

```
for(int i=0; i < (size-1); i++)
    for(int l = 1;  < size; l++)....
```

But in java we use Iterator so how can I do that using the Iterator? (If you can find a way to use the index of the set that would be fine as well).

PS: Sorry, I just moved from C++ to java so I'd need your help starting up.

Comment: ok i found a way to solve this what I need is just convert the hashmap into arraylist.It should be better 

List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>(m.values());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the values implement the `Comparable`. String implements `Comparable<String>` so you're fine (read some tutorial about Comparable if you like).

Do the double loop to get **all** pairs (x,y) and then exclude (x,x) and (y,x) using the `compareTo` method:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(112334,"A");
map.put(221345,"B");
map.put(321411,"C");
map.put(431254,"D");

Collection<String> values = map.values();
for (String str1 : values) {
    for (String str2 : values) {
        if (str1.compareTo(str2) < 0) {
            System.out.println(String.format("unique pair: (%s, %s)", str1, str2));
            // or whatever you want but do not modify map here!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by comparable ?  you want me to do a double loop to see if that pair exist or not ? So if I have N elements then I have to get all N*N pairs and checking ? Is it more faster than I just get N*(N-1)/2 pairs ? I have to say that my set contains more than 100,000 elements ...

Comment: @Nexus made my answer more verbose (1st version was from smartphone). now regarding the performance question: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (you can google for that). first try the simple way. if it turns out to be too slow, then you can still use arrays. or switch back to C. C is good for writing fast programs. java is good for writing readable and maintainable programs.

Comment: ok that sound good , you use Collection instead of Array, I will try a shot :))

Answer (score 0):

Given the rest of your approach, there is nothing wrong with using the two `for` loops as you've posted in your question plus a couple fixes.

```
for(int i=0; i < (size-1); i++)
    for(int l = i+1; l < size; l++)....
```

That said, it certainly wouldn't be my approach to use a `Map` when an array is probably what you really want.

Comment: Sorry , my bad, I think I should be more specific. the (Integer)key here is not storing the index. It store another integer value and can't be used to iterate so imagine it like this
m.put(11234,"A");
m.put(23451,"B");
m.put(31235,"C");
m.put(51233,"D");